# How to convert InputStream to FilePart?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to test this simple function, that receive a file from controller and extract emails from it.

```
    fun extractEmailsFromFile(file: Mono<FilePart>, emailsPerFileLimit: Int): Flux<String> {
        return file
                .flatMap { readFileContent(it) }
                .flatMapMany { textContent -> extractAndValidateEmails(textContent, emailsPerFileLimit) }
    }
```

To do the unit test, I want to put a file on resource folder and read it. How can i convert this inputStream:

```
javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/upload/emails.csv")
```

in a FilePart to pass as parameter in my test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line:

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("upload/emails.csv")`

Besides, in a unit test using JUnit, you can use `TemporaryFolder` rule to create temporary folders and files if necessary. It's quite useful. For more info: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html